# Unable to save data using hibernate.save()

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, hibernate, cascade

I am trying to add Staff object which has staff information, roles and subjects. The code below saves only Staff data not its associated collections data.
I have tried to debug it but didn't understand the issue. The staff object has roles and subjects before saving into database but they are not getting saved in the DB. Surprisingly, the similar code is working while saving Course table data; however, Course does also have collection of Subject class.

It seems to me that Subjects have Course object which may be creating problem, I am not sure why. Please advise how to fix it.

The complete project is available on GitHub(https://github.com/ravinain/practice/tree/master/Java/Spring/SchoolProject)

**Staff.java**

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Staff extends Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private double salary;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "staff", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.ALL})
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "staffs", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
    private Set<Subject> subjects = new HashSet<Subject>();
```

**Role.java**

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @NotNull
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name = "role_staff", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "staff_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @JsonIgnore
    private Staff staff;
```

**Subject.java**

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Subject implements Comparable<Subject>{

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "subject_staff", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "subject_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "staff_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Staff> staffs = new HashSet<Staff>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "subjects", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.DELETE, CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE })
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<Course>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "subjects", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.DELETE, CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE })
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>();
```

DAO Code:

```
public Staff addStaff(Staff staff) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.save(staff);
    return staff;
}
```

POST Request:

```
{"name":"New Test","age":22,"gender":"Female","salary":12000,"roles":[{"id":3,"name":"Teacher"}],"subjects":[{"id":1,"description":"Math"},{"id":2,"description":"English"}]}
```

Comment: Why are you using @JsonIgnore  on  some properties?

Comment: @dsp_user to ignore them while deserializing into JSON format. If I don't use it then deserialization will go to infinite.

Comment: Will that not prevent Hibernate from saving Role and Subject objects (so cascading isn't going to work)? BTW, you're deserializing into POJOs, not JSON. Can you check that the Role and Subject instances are populated (after deserialization)?

Comment: Did you try to get and open a transaction from session object? I can't see it in your code. You also didn't commit the transaction, so how they're supposed to be saved?

Comment: @Moshe Arad, I am using declarative transaction. So on service class I have used **@Transactional** annotation. To commit or rollback is spring's responsibility. You may checkout the project.

Comment: @dsp_user sorry, yes at the time serialization I want to ignore those properties. That's why I have used them. The similar code is working when I save Course data which has Subjects in it. You may look at the complete code given on the link.

Comment: But there is no Course class in your example. Anyway, did you debug your application to make sure that both Role and Subject are populated before you call session.save(staff)?

Comment: @dsp_user yes, it's populated. I fixed the issue by doing like below:

`session.save(staff);
  for (Role role : staff.getRoles()) {
   Role role1 = roleDao.getRole(role.getId());
   role1.setStaff(staff);
  }
  for (Subject subject : staff.getSubjects()) {
   Subject subject1 = subjectDao.getSubject(subject.getId());
   subject1.getStaffs().add(staff);
  }
  session.merge(staff);`